# Is there a way to avoid repeating the same code in multiple Subs with variables?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a vba module that I am trying to make look more professional by removing code that's cut and pasted across nine individual Subs with separate variables for each of the nine. Is there a good way to avoid cutting and pasting?
I've put the beginning portions of just a few of the nine Subs below; each Sub has about 300 lines that's copied (but not included in this question for space).

```
Sub OpenFilterABC()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim s123 As String
        Dim s456 As String
        Dim x789 As String
        
        s123 = "<>ABC"
        s456 = "<>*ABC*"
        x789 = "ABC"
       
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\ABC Today.xlsx"
                      
        Sheets("First Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=s123
                        
        Sheets("Second Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x789
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=s456

'There are an additional 300+ lines per Sub, plus nine total Subs; just shortened it for this question

End Sub

Sub OpenFilterDEF()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim s123 As String
        Dim s456 As String
        Dim x789 As String
        
        s123 = "<>DEF"
        s456 = "<>*DEF*"
        x789 = "DEF"
       
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\DEF Today.xlsx"
                      
        Sheets("First Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=s123
                        
        Sheets("Second Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x789
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=s456
End Sub

Sub OpenFilterGHI()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim s123 As String
        Dim s456 As String
        Dim x789 As String
        
        s123 = "<>GHI"
        s456 = "<>*GHI*"
        x789 = "GHI"
       
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\GHI Today.xlsx"
                      
        Sheets("First Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=s123
                        
        Sheets("Second Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x789
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=s456
End Sub
```

Comment: Too vague to answer in any detail, but code which is copy-pasted is typically a sub or function waiting to be born.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a generic function and pass the variables. And then call the functions as necessary.

```
Sub OpenFilter( s123_Arg As String, s456_Arg As String,x789_Arg As String, Filename_Arg As String)
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim s123 As String
        Dim s456 As String
        Dim x789 As String
        
        s123 = s123_Arg
        s456 = s456_Arg
        x789 = x789_Arg
       
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Filename_Arg
                      
        Sheets("First Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=s123
                        
        Sheets("Second Sheet").Select
            Set rng = Range("$A$1:$ZZ$157000")
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=x789
                rng.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=s456
End Sub

Sub OpenFilterABC()
     Call OpenFilter("<>ABC","<>*ABC*","ABC","C:\Users\Desktop\ABC Today.xlsx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Side notes for OP: [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). and the `s123 = s123_Arg`, `s456 = s456_Arg`, `s789 = x789_Arg` are redundant. Just use `Criteria1:=s123_Arg`, `Criteria1=x789_Arg`, and `Criteria1:=s456_Arg`. Also, `Call` can be removed: `OpenFilter "<>ABC", "<>*ABC*", "ABC", "C:\Users\Desktop\ABC Today.xlsx"`, without parentheses.